# Efficient way to generate a strong eTag Hash code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, etag, asp.net-core-6.0

I am currently implementing the eTag for my GET end points. so using below process to generate & all looks good.

1. Using `ActionFilterAttribute` & overriding the `OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)`.
2. Using `SHA256` to generate the hash.(its working for `Md5` also). As SHA256 is more secure, although late in processing but that is not an issue.
3. I can see the `eTag` & I am adding in to the response header.

**issue:-**
In my GET end point, I call 100 record. so I do get a eTag in runtime & it works. Lets assume i have updated the name of a record/entity, which is a very small update. Logically it should generate a new eTag. But its not. it's giving same old eTag.

it's not the case for single record, as I am using CosmosDb, so i can use the eTag of the cosmosDb, but when I fetch a bunch of record, how to handle it?

I have come across this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) , but wanted to check if effective way of generating eTag is there?

Comment: *Using SHA256 to generate the hash* the hash of what exactly? To generate accurate etags, your hash should be dependant on actual data.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing eTags as opposed to the tried-and-tested `Last-Modified` timestamp?

Comment: Yes @WiktorZychla, its based on the retrieved data. But when calculating the byte[], byte[] data = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)), its considering no change, although there is a small change in the data. So any extra salt/chunk i need to add to the input to generate a new one. or what's the best way?

Comment: Yes @Dai, in some scenario, user may not be passing the timestamp. of course we can force to, but before that want to check if any better approach to check the eTag way.

Comment: FYI, `ETags` are not meant to be secure, so there is zero reason to use a slower but more secure hash algorithm.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry so eTag is not suggested you mean to say?

Comment: @lokanathdas: etags are fine, what kevin only means is that you don't have to use any "secure" hash as etags are not about security.

Comment: Ok, but what i meant was Md5 algorithm is working fine but throwing security issue in security scans, so SHA256 also works fine without any issue. eTag is never for security.

Comment: @lokanathdas What "security scans" are you referring to?

Comment: LIke Hp fortify & veracode etc. But md5/SHA is not an issue. My issue is, eTag(hash code) doesn't consider small change while using any of the algorithm. how to handle it?